# How Do I Delete All The Images from Wordpress

Tags: images, media

I want to delete all the images. By all I means Images from Media Library as well as the from posts. I have 4000 images in wordpress upload directory and each image is attached to a post.

By 'detach' and deleting a image permanently form Media Manger is not removing the image from the Post. :(

I searched and could not find any plugin. There is a plugin to search and delete all unattached / unused images. But I want to delete all the used images from Media Manager, Posts and Any Database References...

This is a great community and I hope I will able to fix this problem...

Thanks!
Rohit

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following, I havent tested it, so look out for typos or errors:

```
$all_posts = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => - 1,
    'post_status' => 'any',
    'post_type' => get_post_types('', 'names') ,
));

foreach($all_posts as $all_post) {
    delete_post_media($all_post->ID);
}

function delete_post_media($post_id)
{
    if (!isset($post_id)) return;
    elseif ($post_id == 0) return;
    elseif (is_array($post_id)) return;
    else {
            $attachments = get_posts(array(
                    'post_type' => 'attachment',
                    'posts_per_page' => - 1,
                    'post_status' => 'any',
                    'post_parent' => $post_id
            ));
            foreach($attachments as $attachment) {
                    if (false === wp_delete_attachment($attachment->ID)) {

                            // Log failure to delete attachment.

                    }
            }
    }
}
```